# Riemann-Stieltjes Integration-IVT

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration, means

I need to show this,

> Suppose that $f,g: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are continuous.
> Show that exist $\eta \in (a,b)$ such that
> $$g(\eta)\int_a^\eta f(x)dx=f(\eta)\int_\eta^b g(x)dx  $$

I defined $F(x):= \int_a^x f(x)dx$,  $G(x):= \int_a^x g(x)dx$ and $ h: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $h(x)=F(x)(G(x)-G(b))$, $h'$ exist, so

\begin{align}
h'(x)&=F'(x)(G(x)-G(b))+ G'(x)F(x)\\
&=f(x) \left(  \int_a^x g(x)dx -\int_a^b g(x)dx  \right)+g(x) \int_a^x f(x)dx\\
&=f(x)\left(-\int_x^b g(x)dx  \right)+g(x) \int_a^x f(x)dx\\
&= g(x) \int_a^x f(x)dx-f(x)\int_x^b g(x)dx
\end{align}

As $h$  is continuous and differentiable in $(a,b)$ and $h(a)=h(b)=0$, there exists $c \in (a,b)$ such that $h'(c)=h(c)$.

$$h'(c)=g(c) \int_a^c f(x)dx-f(c)\int_c^b g(x)dx$$ and
$$h(c)=\left(\int_a^c f(x)dx  \right)\left(-\int_c^b g(x)dx  \right)$$

At this step I'm stuck, can someone help me?

Comment: By Rolle’s theorem there exists $c$ such that $h’(c) = 0$. With this you are done.